# Create a shortcut with added options

Tags: powershell, symlink

I have read all of the questions about creating a shortcut with PowerShell, but I still cannot find an answer to my question about having switches at the end of the executable.  I found the following code here, but I also need to add switches at the end.  I need my shortcut to also contain **"/environment  code" **  I have tried adding it with a **&** or a **+** but they both cause errors.

The answer I found also mentions how to use com objects, but I do not know what they are, or how to use them if I ever have to come back and modify this in the future.

```
    New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\temp" -Name "Welcome.lnk" -Value "c:\welcome\welcomelauncher.exe"
```

I am hoping to make it read like this:
[image: Sortcut Target Line]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see a + or an &. Probably better to show what exactly you want to end up with

Comment: What error does it give you

Comment: Symbolic links and shortcuts are different things
If you need an argument to your shortcut, look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815286/creating-quoted-path-for-shortcut-with-arguments-in-powershell